# ¿Cómo crear el evento en el calendario del organizador?

Tags: c#, outlook, icalendar

Estoy implementando en una aplicación de Windows Form C# una función para el seguimiento de clientes, que consta de registrar citas para reuniones. Hasta ahora ya se envían correctamente las solicitudes de asistencia a la reunión y a los invitados se les agrega directamente a su calendario, pero **el evento no se agrega al calendario del organizador** por lo que al momento de que los asistentes responden se crea conflicto ya que no existe como tal.

Este es el método que ejecuta tal función, ¿será que necesito agregar algo mas? de ser así ¿qué podría ser?

```
public string crearCita()
    {
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
        email.From = new MailAddress("organizador@outlook.com");
        email.To.Add("invitado01@outlook.com");
        email.Subject = "Reunión";
        email.Body = "Hola, está cordialmente invitado a la reunión...;
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        email.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        smtp = new SmtpClient();

        string locacion = "Calle #0 Col. Nombre";
        string inicio = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(2)).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
        string fin = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(4)).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");

        // iCal
        IICalendar iCal = new iCalendar();
        iCal.Method = "REQUEST";
        Guid uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        iCal.ProductID = uid.ToString();

        // Create an event and attach it to the iCalendar.
        Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();
        evt.UID = uid.ToString();
        evt.Class = "PUBLIC";
        evt.Created = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        evt.DTStamp = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        evt.Transparency = TransparencyType.Transparent;

        // Set the event start / end times
        evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(2020, 09, 15, 8, 0, 0);
        evt.End = new iCalDateTime(2020, 09, 15, 8, 15, 0);
        evt.Location = locacion;

        // Organizer
        var organizer = new Organizer(email.From.ToString());
        evt.Organizer = organizer;

        // Set the longer description of the event, plain text
        evt.Description = email.Body;

        // Event description HTML text
        var prop = new CalendarProperty("X-ALT-DESC");
        prop.AddParameter("FMTTYPE", "text/html");
        prop.AddValue(email.Body);
        evt.AddProperty(prop);

        

        // Set the one-line summary of the event
        evt.Summary = email.Subject;
        evt.Priority = 1;
       

        // Alarm
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        alarm.Action = AlarmAction.Display;
        alarm.Summary = "Ya está próxima la cita  " + email.Subject;
        alarm.Trigger = new Trigger(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-30));
        alarm.AddProperty("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS", "BUSY");
        evt.Alarms.Add(alarm);


        IAttendee at = new Attendee("mailto:" + email.To[0].Address);
        at.RSVP = true;
        at.Type = "GROUP";
        evt.Attendees.Add(at);

        iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer();

        // the .ics File as a string
        string iCalStr = serializer.SerializeToString(iCal);

        ContentType ct = new ContentType("text/calendar");
        ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        ct.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");

        AlternateView aCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(iCalStr, ct);
        email.AlternateViews.Add(aCal);
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(email);
            return "Se creo la invitación";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "The following error occurred: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```